# Adding 15 years to an existing date

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Sample data

```
column1    
01-JAN-10 
01-jan-90
```

like so much data is there

I want out put like

```
column2
31-dec-25
31-dec-15
```

For this give me formula.
I tried like `=Year(A1)+15` but it doesn't giving proper output

Comment: Is it Excel or is it Calc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution with LibreOffice Calc:

[image]

It uses `=DATE(YEAR(A2)+15,12,31)` where `DATE(<year>,<month>,<day>)`.

Answer (score 1):

`=DATE(YEAR(A1)+15)`

You need to use the date function. More information and more example at

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/add-dates-HP003056112.aspx#BMadd_a_number_of_years_to_a_date

This works for excel and LibreOffice Calc

Answer (score 0):

More elegant solution is (using the exact source info above) ...

=Edate(A2,15*12) - 1

Edate will giving you the same date, 15 years on .. so 1 Jan 25, subtract 1 gives you the previous day.

Parameter is months, so either hard code the '15', or for variable number of years, point to a cell.

Also works for leap years ...

If A2 = 29 Feb 2020,

=Edate(A2,12) gives 28 Feb 2021;
=Edate(A2,12) + 1 gives 1 Mar 2021